# Store data to db using Nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm starting to learn Vue JS and now trying to learn in nativescript-vue.
What should I do in order to have an offline DB where I can store my data without using internet connection. I heard about Firebase but I think I can't use my app if I don't have an internet connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase with persistence enabled or you can use sqlite  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sqlite) with vuex quite nicely.

Comment: Does firebase work like when you add some data on your app then save it, it saves it to firebase of course and then when you try to open your app without internet connection, is the data will be accessible in your phone?

Comment: or like this.
when I open my app I add my FirstName then save it to Firebase, turned off my internet and open my app again. is my name will be displayed? or the app is still accessible even without internet?

Comment: see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Comment: just add `  firebase.init({
    persist: true
  });`

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:
If you use applications settings within your app you can store simple data in a json object.

If you check out: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/key-value-local-storage-in-a-vue.js-nativescript-app-with-vuex

This article includes a step by step example of how to implement including using vuex store.

from that page: (store)

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as ApplicationSettings from "application-settings";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: ""
    },
    mutations: {
        load(state) {
            if(ApplicationSettings.getString("store")) {
                this.replaceState(
                    Object.assign(state, JSON.parse(ApplicationSettings.getString("store")))
                );
            }
        },
        save(state, data) {
            state.firstname = data.firstname;
            state.lastname = data.lastname;
        }
    }
});

Vue.prototype.$store = store;

module.exports = store;
```

Then save in your app with:

```
methods: {
    save() {
        this.$store.commit("save", this.input);
    },

}
```

You will need to add a mutation to save to application settings as well:

a simple way to do that is add to the save mutation:

```
 save(state, data) {
                state.firstname = data.firstname;
                state.lastname = data.lastname;
                ApplicationSettings.setString("store", JSON.stringify(state));
            }
```